# Saving large model in pySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, word2vec

I have word2vec model in spark that I would like to save to a file to make it easier to load later.

When I run the save method, I get the following:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage
failure: Serialized task 130:0 was 413893420 bytes, which exceeds max 
allowed: spark.akka.frameSize (134217728 bytes) - reserved (204800 
bytes). Consider increasing spark.akka.frameSize or using broadcast 
variables for large values.
```

I did some research and it looks like the frameSize is still capped so I would like to explore alternatives in case I run into a similar issues with a larger model in the future.

I just to create a broadcast variable with the model, but that failed with the following exception.

```
brd = sc.broadcast(model)

Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference 
SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. 
SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run 
on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

I guess I can run getVectors and export the date somehow like that, but I would be able to easily load the model. Does anyone know of any alternatives I can take?

Thanks

Comment: The second approach is simply invalid. In the first case have you followed the suggestions and adjusted `spark.akka.frameSize`?

Comment: spark.akka.frameSize should not be greater than 2047 MB, what do I do if it becomes larger then that?